# Does Groovy auto-box boolean to Object by default?

Tags: java, groovy, boxing

Consider this Java class:

```
public class Demo {

    public void a(boolean a){
        System.out.println("boolean was called");
    }

    public void a(Object a){
        System.out.println("Object was called");
    }

}
```

Groovy class:

```
class Groovy {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def demo = new Demo()
        demo.a(true)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Object was called
```

Writing a test for it in Groovy and passing in a primitive `true` calls `a(Object)` instead.

Is this intended behaviour and how can I call the other method? (I'm on version 2.4.6)

FYI this causes problems with EasyMock (#[175890293](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/issues/180#issue-175890293))

Comment: I have added my answer to the easymock thread with the full explanation of the issue and its workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer is only valid pre Groovy 2.4.8 so I will leave it there as it is. In 2.4.8 this behaviour has been fixed (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7933). Therefore, the new order for resolving methods in this example would be:

1) Boolean (wrapped)

2) boolean

3) Object

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is intended, see the groovy manual:

http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html

> Groovy supports the same primitive types as those defined by the Java
>   Language Specification:
>
> [...]
>
> boolean type (exactly true or false)
>
> [...]
>
> While Groovy declares and stores primitive fields and variables as
>   primitives, because it uses Objects for everything, it autowraps
>   references to primitives. Just like Java, the wrappers it uses are
>
> Table 1. primitive wrappers

```
Primitive type      Wrapper class
boolean             Boolean
```

Comment: `it uses Objects for everything` the key phrase

Answer (score 1):

Groovy autowraps primitives, so it is intended behaviour.

Also due to the autowrapping, the method resolution is different from Java, which causes your issue:

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-differences-java.html#_primitives_and_wrappers

The solution for your problem is to cast your "true" constant to a boolean primitive in the method call.

```
class Groovy {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def demo = new Demo()
        demo.a((boolean) true)
    }
}
```

This prints "boolean was called".